# Auto-deleting particular records in one table of Oracle database using SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've got question concerning auto deleting particular records in one table of Oracle database using SQL.

I am making small academic project of database for private clinic and I have to design Oracle database and client application in Java.
One of my ideas is to arrange table "Visits" which stores all patients visits which took place in the past for history purposes. Aforementioned table will grow pretty fast so it will have weak searching performance.
So the idea is to make smaller table called "currentVisits" which holds only appointments for future visits because it will be much faster to search through ~1000 records than few millions after few years.

My question is how to implement auto deleting records in SQL from temporary table "currentVisits" after they took place.
Both tables will store fields like dateOfVisit, patientName, doctorID etc.
Is there any possibility to make it work in simple way? For example using triggers?

I am quite new in this topic so thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about the data size.  Millions of records is not particularly large for a database on modern computing hardware.  You will need an appropriate data structure, however.

In this case, you will want an index on the column that indicates current records.  In all likelihood, the current records will be appended onto the end of the table, so they will tend to be congregating on a handful of data pages.  This is a good thing.

If you have a heavy deletion load on the table, or you are using a clustered index, then the pages with the current records might be spread throughout the database.  In that case, you want to include the "current" column in the clustered index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Actualy our teacher suggested such a solution but he's deliberately complicating things i think. I belive your solution is better and I will try to organise things like you said.
Cheers :)